# How can I disable or hide warnings and errors shown in the backend?

Tags: 8, debugging

Is there a way to disable or hide warnings and errors shown in the backend? For example when a user creates a node and some error occurs on the live page (image or helper class not found), then there is a big red box with around 25 lines of error message on each page in the backend.

For my editors who have to write 100 nodes a day it's very annoying.

Edit:

`logging & error -> error messages` is set to display NONE.

Comment: Obviously you are running your live site with dev settings. Did you check settings.php?

Comment: @4k4 you are right. i forgot to remove $config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose'; in my settings.php. thank you very much

Comment: In my settings.php, `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` is not exists. But still notices and warnings are showing in page. Any other configuration in drupal 8 to hide notice and warning messages?.

Comment: `Development->Error&logging->Display Errors` is set as `None`

Comment: What error? What's it saying? Can you edit your question, please, to add an example? As I'd say the best answer here is to help you fix that error instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 4):

You actually should fix the error.

And since it's not a very good idea to globally disable all errors and warnings for all roles, please use [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) to disable error messages based on configurable conditions.

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users. The core Drupal message system as offered by `drupal_set_message`
>   is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users.
>   However not all Drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages
>   sent out by Drupal core and all modules to their users. This module
>   gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out
>   messages shown to the end users.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly
> - Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> - Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> - Disable all filtering for specific users.
> - Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> - Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> - Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.